# Android Automatic Circular Gallery

Tags: android, android-animation, android-gallery

I am having gallery widget contains 1-10 images to slide. I know that when I stripe the screen , the images scroll from left to right. I want automatic circular gallery after 10 automatically start by first image, is there any automatic circular adapter or way ???

```
         final Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
         g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
         Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
        R.anim.rotate_indefinitely);

        animation.getInterpolator();
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setStartOffset(200);
        animation.setRepeatMode(2);
        animation.setFillAfter(false);
        animation.setFillEnabled(true);

        g.setAnimation(animation);
        g.startAnimation(animation);
```

but I only see the first image is animated ..

Take a look at my [Video](http://vimeo.com/12817335) ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write a SpinnerAdapter for the Gallery that returns Integer.MAX_VALUE in it's getCount() method. Then, when returning a View in getDropDownView() and getView(), apply modulo of the actual items count to the `position` argument.

Comment: You want an endless Gallery, starting from first item after scrolling to last, right? So you make it think it holds more items than present, and add position %= itemsCount in Adapter's getView() to have it queue the first item after the last one.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a simplest solution.
Just `returns Integer.MAX_VALUE in it's getCount() method`
This will make infinite pool at right side.
To make it both sided
`pass Integer.MAX_VALUE/2 in the position of child in setSelection(position, animate)`
Cool.

Comment: Thanks alot Pervez Alam. You saved my day.